# continue interrupted downloading of packages without having to redownload [from apt-get download some-package]

Tags: apt, software-installation

When installing packages with `apt-get install`, it first starts to download all needed packages and then installs them one by one.

But, If you use `apt-get download`, and interrupt the process during the first phase, and start over again, it downloads all packages again from scratch (erasing any partially-downloaded .deb files).

How can I continue the aborted download process without re-downloading the already received partial data?

Comment: @A.B. I think he wants to keep the partial downloads and just continue with downloading the rest. So that no data is downloaded twice. This might be useful for huge packages and people with slow connections. - I edited the question to sound like that. If I understood it falsely, please feel free to roll the edit back, rubo77!

Comment: @ByteCommander It is exactly what `apt-get` does always! It never re-downloads partially downloaded data

Comment: Now, as I read this again, I think so too, but I am sure, that, last year, when I asked this, I asked, because I was so unhappy, that it didn't keep the already downloaded parts in my case. Can you think of a setup, where id doesn't keep the partial downloads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wget -v -d -nc -c -S --random-wait --keep-badhash\
https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser_105.0.5195.102-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb
```

## REBUTTAL & REAL WORKING SOLUTION

Counter-point:
If using **`apt-get download`**, and restarting, then yes it DOES RESTART OVER FROM SCRATCH.

Platform:
I'm using Ubuntu Bionic - 18.04 LTS - x86 (32bit) (...as the engine under Bodhi_Linux_5.1.0's bootable ISO - LiveCD).

again...
The answer to this is if using the --download-only option,
or
`apt-get download some-package`
as
opposed to
`apt-get install some-package`
...

if using
`apt-get download somepackage`
then
YES
it WILL RESTART the download FROM SCRATCH.

## SOLUTION

My solution to this:

1. backup the existing PARTIALLY-DOWNLOADED .deb file to .deb.BAK
2. use apt-get's `--print-uris` option to show me the URL of the .deb file to download
3. resume partial-download using `wget -c` instead of apt-get.... like so:
   `wget -v -d -S -c [--random-wait] [--keep-badhash] https://url-to-file/path/some0package.deb`

Code Template for the above steps:

1. `$ cp some0package.deb some0package.deb.BAK`
2. `$ apt-get --print-uris download some0package`
3. `$ wget -v -d -c -S --random-wait --keep-badhash [copy & paste here the full https://URL you got from the previous command, but NOT the other rest of that output]`

Code EXAMPLE
using chromium-browser:

```
$ cp\
chromium-browser_105.0.5195.102-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb\
chromium-browser_105.0.5195.102-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb.BAK

$ apt-get download --print-uris chromium-browser
```

[RESULTING OUTPUT:]

```
https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser_105.0.5195.102-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb' chromium-browser_105.0.5195.102-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb 79183996 SHA512:bc34c6241b4200bf9c4c8a7dccba5415daec9623741328146bf4d8edb91d3db7489d5c467162075caf9266644369ac2af0c41cd6b4e320e9c110a6e71411b4ce
```

In the above output,
the `--print-uris` option gives us several pieces of info; more than we need.

- **the URL path to** the package-file on the server-side ((THIS FULL URL IS WHAT WE NEED TO COPY!))
- the filename as it expects will be locally on your PC
- the total complete filesize on the SERVERside;
- an SHA512 hash
  (to do a comparison after it's been downloaded)

Of these,
I only need to copy

- the first part, the URL
- optional: the SHA512 hash (if i wish to compare after-download that it matches the server's copy)
  :

`$ wget -v -d -c -S --random-wait --keep-badhas https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser_105.0.5195.102-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb`

This worked for me!
In summary:

0. I started with the command:
   `$ apt-get download chromium-browser`
1. It got interrupted / I canceled (ctrl-c).
2. I backed up the existing file:
   `$ cp [local-filename.deb] [local-filename.deb.BAK]`
3. I grabbed the web URL to use via:
   `$ apt-get download --print-uris chromium-browser`
4. I highlighted & COPIED TO CLIPBOARD the first part of the OUTPUT from that command, which (for ME) ended up being (don't use this; use the one you get in your terminal )
   https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser_105.0.5195.102-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb
5. I then used `wget -c` (the '-c' means 'continue an existing download')... (with added verbose, so i could see if anything went wrong what the problem is) .... and PASTED the URL i'd gotten from the previous command, like so:

`$ wget -v -d -c -S --random-wait --keep-badhash\`

`https://[URL-you-got-and-copied-from-output-of-the-previous-command]`
`somepackage.deb`

Answer (score 3):

Your claim that

> If you interrupt the process during the first phase, and start over again, it downloads all packages again.

is **completely wrong!** Apt is a smart package management system and it never re-downloads packages required to satisfy an installation request twice, not even for a single package or .deb file.

Those `.deb` files which are half-downloaded reside in `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial` directory and with `ls` command (in 16.04, you need to use `sudo ls`) you can check those files there.

You can verify this by looking at the [`apt-get` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-get.8.html), where it says about `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/`

```
  /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/
  Storage area for package files in transit. Configuration Item:
  Dir::Cache::Archives (partial will be implicitly appended)
```

You can even pick of one of those files and manually resume download using `wget -c`.

In the background, Apt uses `wget` program with `-c` switch, which from [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/wget.1.html) means

```
-c,  --continue                  resume getting a partially-downloaded file
```